# Call to test a flexible CV package on LaTeX under final stages of development

Tags: discussion, feature-request, licensing

The package is here:

https://gitlab.com/koleygr/flexible-cv

and I am tending to upload on TUG soon, but surely some testing is needed and as I have developed the most of its parts a while (some years) ago, I would like your comments/ feature requests etc before upload

Actual questions except the too general above test/feature request
:

Do you think I could upload on TUG with a licence similar to the one on my gitlab project? If not... Is there a way to add the source somewhere easily discover-able that could use such a license

The license:

flexible-CV project is lisenced under these terms:

1. You should always be available to share the code or any edit that you have made in the template (So, this project and its derivatives will remain always open source)
2. You may use it without any charge for personal reasons.
3. If you use it for any kind of commersial reason, and if you have the ability to do so, you have to donate to someone (not nesesserily the creator) that has survival needs of money or of your donation in any way.
4. This license has to be used in any derivative work of this original project with an active link to this project too inside the lisence.

Comment: I am not sure the license would be okay particulary line 3: `3. If you use it for any kind of commersial reason, and if you have the ability to do so, you have to donate to someone (not nesesserily the creator) that has survival needs of money or of your donation in any way.` but I am not an expert. I think to go onto TeXlive (if this is what you want) it has to be a particular free license.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JamesT. Yes, surely I have to re-check at least how I will add this particular sentence, but I hope I will find a legally accepted way to do it since this is the most important term of the licence for me. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I am busy with a report but in the near future once the coding/license has been finalised let me know and I can help spell check it for you prior to uploading if this is helpful `:)`

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic here as it's not about TeX-sx community aspects, so I will close. That said, I suggest you pick a standard license: it's well known that 'DIY licenses' are problematic.